# insert data to table from select statment

Tags: sql-server-2008

i worked on two tables (persons) and (payments) .payments table contain columns (payment_id , payment_value , payment_class , date , name , person_id) now i want to insert data to payments by select from persons table like that

```
insert into Payments(payment_id , payment_value , payment_class , date , name , person_id)
select person_id , person_name , person_status from Persons where person_status = 'sub'
```

how to insert payments to every person selected from persons table ..

Comment: What values do you want to insert? You are telling the insert that you will fill all those column but them you select some other different values from persons table. That will not work

Comment: i just want fill date column with date value i will declare it later and all other columns i want it null

Comment: Want to fill the date value with what? the current time?

Comment: yes .. date value with current time

Comment: And you want the person_id also, right? and the name in payments, is it from a person?

Comment: ok .. my friend .. i want insert payment with only date value and all other column null to each person selected in query

Comment: no the name in payment is not in persons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement, the following query inserts a record with the current date and all other columns null in table payments, for each person

```
INSERT INTO Payments (payment_id,payment_value,payment_class,date,name,person_id)
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, GETDATE(), NULL, NULL
FROM Persons
WHERE person_status = 'sub';
```

If you want to have person_id extracted directly from table persons, you can do:

```
INSERT INTO Payments (payment_id,payment_value,payment_class,date,name,person_id)
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, GETDATE(), NULL, person_id
FROM Persons
WHERE person_status = 'sub';
```

Comment: thanks very much .. one another thing .. if i want change null to parameter take its value from textbox .. and payment_id is primary key .. how can i increase 1 to max value in table  to each new record

Comment: You should have it as identity column ([see this answer on how to change it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6777807/1385896)) and don't pass it at all, and it will get automatically incremented.

Comment: ok i know that but identity cause problem for me .. i want the numbers complete ... not when i delete third row .. the new row will be 4 .. i don't want that !!!

Comment: @user3038625. You can calculate the max in that query, but imagine you have 5 and delete the number 2, when you select the max, it will be 5, and you do +1, and it inserts as 6, but you will still have a hole in your ids. The identity is the best way to handle this. If you need them ordered and you need the to get the records with a column ordered as if there was no holes you can use a rank() (look it up in stackoverflow, there are lots of examples)