# Insert & Select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a column EAC into Projectdetails. 
Table 1 : [Projectdetails] 
Table 2 : ['RAC']

```
 (SELECT b.[EAC]  FROM [dbo].[Projectdetails] a 
  INNER JOIN [dbo].['RAC'] b ON a.[ProjectKey]= b.[Project _ID])
```

works fine and return me 421 rows.

However the following query does not work :

```
  Insert into [dbo].[Projectdetails]([EAC])
  (SELECT b.[EAC]  FROM [dbo].[Projectdetails] a 
   INNER JOIN [dbo].['RAC'] b ON a.[ProjectKey]= b.[Project _ID])
```

returns me Cannot insert the value NULL into column ProjectKey

Comment: Just to be sure I understand - you're attempting to add and populate the `EAC` column to your existing rows, right?

Comment: Try running `(SELECT b.[EAC]  FROM [dbo].[Projectdetails] a 
  INNER JOIN [dbo].['RAC'] b ON a.[ProjectKey]= b.[Project _ID] WHERE b.EAC IS NULL)`. If you find at least one record then there is your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you really want an `update`:

```
update pd
    set EAC = r.EAC
    from [dbo].[Projectdetails] pd join
         [dbo].['RAC'] r
         on pd.[ProjectKey] = r.[Project _ID]);
```

By the way, putting single quotes in a table name seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @SunnyKP . . . You need to check the data types for the two `EAC` columns.  It would appear that they are different.  You have to decide what to do when the value from one table doesn't fit in the other table.

Comment: This code helped. The data types were different and when I put both of them to same and it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess, ProjectKey is a primary key as it's NOT NULL. So when you are
>   trying to insert new row in this table without providing any specific
>   value for this column, so sqlserver is trying to add NULL as a default
>   value. But as this is NOT NULL column it's giving you error.
>
> The best solution to make it work is make this column as
>   auto-increment column. Like this

[Sql Server add auto increment primary key to existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862385/sql-server-add-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-table)

[SQL Server, How to set auto increment after creating a table without data loss?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084572/sql-server-how-to-set-auto-increment-after-creating-a-table-without-data-loss)