# Add a column ID with a unique value for each row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing table with existing data and I want to add new column (named ID) with auto-increment and I want to add a unique value for each row.

Is there an other way than fetching all data and do an update for each row to set this value ?

Comment: this topic is duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862385/sql-server-add-auto-increment-primary-key-to-existing-table]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need it in a `SELECT`:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ...A ORDER VALUE) as id
FROM yourTable
```

If you need it in your table:

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD id int identity(1,1)
```

Here is a demo for the output of the `ALTER TABLE`:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(name nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO #temp(name) VALUES(N'Kai'),(N'Bernd'),(N'Flo'),(N'Pete')

SELECT * FROM #temp

-- This is what you need to do
ALTER TABLE #temp 
ADD id int identity(1,1) -- This will add and fill the new column

SELECT * FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: By adding the column ID, it won't set a value for each row, Isn't ? Each value will be NULL.

Comment: @SeyoS - Not if the column is defined as `identity(1,1)`

Comment: Hi, I've added a demo to show you the output. The values will be inserted not null. 
@Tanner And no, partition by is if you want to group it and number it per group.