# How to add unique identifier in all rows of a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have imported a `.csv` with 60 million rows and I want to index them for faster queries. If I need to add a column with automatically generated unique identifiers, how can I do that? It's my first time with SQL Server.

Comment: Use Identity property on a new column of data type INT,  GUID is 16 bytes data type and not the best option for a unique identifier column. INT is only 4 bytes and sequential and much faster for SQL Server to work with.

Comment: Use [IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I am very new to this and your answer leaves me with no clues. Could you point me to a article with step by step instructions.

Comment: See: @marc_s' answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4862427/880990

Answer (score 3):

Now, after importing data, you have a table with some columns.

If you want to add an index, you can index already existing columns, see [CREATE INDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for reference.

But, if you want to have some `ID` column, you have to first add it to your table using following command:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY
```

Which will automatically number your existing records starting with 1, make it primary key, which automatically make it an clustered index.

Comment: If you want to do this using the Management Studio instead of writing Transact-SQL code, have a look at [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-primary-keys?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: Hi friends, I liked the answers, however I can not upvote it as my reputation is less than 15, probably because I am a new user..

Comment: @KaushalKumar If my answer helped, you should accept it by checking green mark on the left.